# Is there any specific gem/library for RAILS which can help in performing transactions like credit & debit amount from a bank account?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, currency, banking

Though I can add two methods in my model saying credit and debit I am curious to know if there is any gem that might have more features within and which might help me in future when actually application grows.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to look into the [Stripe](https://rubygems.org/gems/stripe/versions/2.0.1) gem